# Is this the right way to use private in Java?

Tags: java

```
class ShopSimulation extends Simulation {
 18     private Event[] initEvents;
 29     private int numOfCounters;
 30     private int id = 0;
 31     private double arrivalTime;
 32     private double serviceTime;
 33
 34     public ShopSimulation(Scanner sc) {
 35         initEvents = new Event[sc.nextInt()];
 36         numOfCounters = sc.nextInt();
 37
 38         Shop initShop = new Shop(numOfCounters, initEvents.length);
 39         Customer[] customerList = initShop.getCustomerList();
 40         Counter[] counterList = initShop.getCounterList();
 41
 42         id = 0;
 43         while (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
 44             arrivalTime = sc.nextDouble();
 45             serviceTime = sc.nextDouble();
 46             Customer currentCustomer = customerList[id];
 47             // Set the customer arrivalTime and seriveTime
 48             currentCustomer.setTimings(arrivalTime, serviceTime);
 49
 50             initEvents[id] = new ArrivalEvent(arrivalTime, counterList, customerList[id]);
 51
 52             id += 1;
 53         }
 54     }
```

I am unsure if this is the right way to implement private in Java. What I understood about private is just to prevent it from being accessed by other class. Thus, if the variable is not used by other class, I should private it.

Comment: Yes.  See also here - https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/default-scope-in-java/

Comment: Yes if something shouldnt be accessible outside the class it is declared as private, you can use getters and setters to access these variables, it is a good practice.

Comment: Exactly. Declare variables where you NEED them. Only use a member variable if it is necessary. And for a normal class, usually ALL member variables should be private (and final) where possible, and only allow access via getters and setters, where you check conditions. If member variables are TRULY IMMUTABLE, you could expose those with the public keyword. Of if you just have property bags, i.e. a class that has mostly member variables and not much else and where access to the state is not too relevant, like http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/awt/GridBagConstraints-source.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes its correct. 
But its not a good practice to declare all the variable initialization statement at the beginning. You are not coding in c anymore.

Can leave some as default. No problem.
Just use the `private` musk tor the sensitive data.

**Hope you find this useful .**

Comment: please don't mix variable and fields. something that you talking about is fields.